# Pandas convert some value in row into columns if they have a common key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem in python. My table in xlsx. looks like this:

| COMPANY | ID NUMBER | FUNCTION | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | director | Smith |
| A | 123 | partner | Jones |
| A | 123 | secretary | Evans |
| B | 456 | partner | Brown |
| B | 456 | manager | Wilson |

And I need convert rows which have same ID NUMBER to columns. I need all rows with same id to appear on only one row. Like this:

| COMPANY | ID NUMBER | FUNCTION | FUNCTION 2 | FUNCTION 3 | NAME | NAME 2 | NAME 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | director | partner | secretary | Smith | Jones | Evans |
| B | 456 | partner | manager |  | Brown | Wilson |  |

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73400200/19534628) question on SO from yesterday is very similar. Maybe it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First greate helper column `g` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then in list comprehension flatten MultiIndex, last convert Index to columns:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['COMPANY','ID NUMBER']).cumcount()

df = df.pivot(['COMPANY','ID NUMBER'], 'g').fillna('')
df.columns = [f'{a} {b+1}' if b > 0 else a for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  COMPANY  ID NUMBER  FUNCTION FUNCTION 2 FUNCTION 3   NAME  NAME 2 NAME 3
0       A        123  director    partner  secretary  Smith   Jones  Evans
1       B        456   partner    manager             Brown  Wilson
```